# Active window and inactive windows look almost the same in MacOS

Tags: macos

I often have the problem that I am not sure which window is the active one. This leads to me `cmd+tabbing` just to find out which window is the active one.

I did not have this problem on Windows where the top bars are different enough that I can see which window as active without having to focus my gaze on the top bars.

How can I become more certain about which is the active windows?

I have searched a bit for apps that highlight the current window. But the one's that I have found have not been satisfactory. Apps like Focus and Blur make my other windows darker and harder to read. Hodor clashes with the beauty of the OS and is not maintained.

Comment: I have the same issue - with large monitors connected to my macbook pro, it is almost impossible to see which window is active.  It makes finding windows hard. Frequently I have to close the app and open it to find its window, as its "hidden" in all the other windows even though its active.

Answer (score 3):

You can make it easier to differentiate active and in active windows with a setting in macOS:

**System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Increase contrast**

As the name implies it will increase the contrast of all UI elements.

Pay attention to the apps's window controls/'stoplights' for closing/minimizing/maximizing a window. They will turn gray if a window is inactive An inactive window will have a lighter color than an active one:

[image: macOS windows controls]

Comment: That is a nice setting for similar purposes to my question, but it does not seem to make the active window specifically easier to differentiate

Comment: @user1283776 Not sure about the increase contrast setting, but the stoplight icons are definitely different as author also noted. Thanks @oa!

Answer (score 1):

There are products out there that solve this problem:
https://fiplab.com/apps/window-focus-for-mac

Or try this free open-sourced app:
https://github.com/puffnfresh/Honer.app

Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with them in anyway.